# .vimrc set paste not taking effect consistently

Tags: vim

It seems like my 'set paste' option in .vimrc isn't being picked up. When I start vim and go to to insert mode, I get insert (paste) as expected. However when I paste from my clipboard with apple-V, the text is progressively indented at each line as if I didn't have paste mode on. Then I manually enter :set paste and try again, and the text is formatted properly.

Also it seems like the autoindent is spotty even though it's explicitly set as well.

This is vim 7.3 on OSX Lion. Thanks!

```
set paste 
set autoindent
syntax on

colorscheme elflord

set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
```

Answer (score 4):

`set paste` has no business being in your `~/.vimrc` as it conflicts with a number of useful options.

The only use for `:set paste` is to reset a bunch of indentation-related options to allow your text to be pasted "correctly" when you use the mouse or your system's "paste" facilities. It's probably a good idea to read `:h pastetoggle`.

In such a situation, you are supposed to do `:set paste` before you paste and `:set nopaste` afterwards.

If your Vim has clipboard support built-in (`:echo has('clipboard')` should return `1`) and you work locally, I highly recommend you use `"+y` and `"+p` instead.

Comment: That clarifies the issues I'm having, thanks. Is there a way to have them set by default though?

Comment: What do you mean? `set paste` **must absolutely never be set by default.** Never. Never. Never. Never. It has too many side effects.

Comment: I think this is a case of a noob (me) coming to a new piece of technology and wanting to use it in a basic way. I just want to paste text and make it look right with a minimum of configuration. The side effects you're referring to I don't seem to encounter. I like vim because it's simple, and I was hoping the configuration was equally simple.

Comment: You don't need any configuration. That's the point. What you need is to use the right command: `y` to copy ("yank") and `p` to paste ("put"). Another thing you need is to install a proper build because, like on every UNIX-y OS, the default Vim is unsuitable for programming. Also, allow me to add that approaching Vim like if it was just another editor is a mistake. Trust me, I did the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The options `paste` and `autoindent` don't get along with each other. I suggest to leave `autoindent` on and map to a function key `<F10>` the toggle of the `paste` option, like:

```
:map <F10> :set invpaste<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. On the mac keyboard I'm using, the function keys need a mod key so they're less convenient. I'm trying to figure a way to have vim launch with the specific config I prefer ... I'll study some more.